# DocuSign: Auto-Place doesn't work with sign tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to add anchor tagging when I create a new envelope, but the tab to sign doesn't appear.

I've followed these steps:

1. Created a template

POST {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/templates

```
    {"name": "Template 1",
        "emailBlurb": "Blurb Test",
         "emailSubject": "Subject Test",
         "documents": [{
           "documentId": "1",
           "name": "Document1",
           "fileExtension": "pdf",
           "order": "1",
           "documentBase64":"base64codehere" }]
   }
```

2. Created an envelope

POST {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes

```
{"status": "created", "templateId": "{{templateId}}" }
```

3. Add recipient to the envelope

POST {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients

```
       {
     "signers": [
       {
        "userName" : "Sender 1",
         "email": "sender1email@gmail.com",
         "name": "Sender 1",
         "clientUserId": "SenderOne" ,
         "recipientId": "1",
         "roleName" : "SenderMember",
         "routingOrder": "1",
         "tabs": {
           "signHereTabs": [
               {
               "anchorString": "\\sn1\\",
                   "anchorXOffset": "20",
                   "anchorYOffset": "10",
                   "anchorUnits": "pixels"
               }            
           ]
       }
       },
               {
        "userName" : "Sender2",
         "email": "sender2email@gmail.com",
         "name": "Sender2",
         "clientUserId": "Sender2C" ,
         "recipientId": "2",
         "roleName" : "SenderMember2",
         "routingOrder": "2",
         "tabs": {
           "signHereTabs": [
               {
               "anchorString": "\\sn1\\",
                   "anchorXOffset": "20",
                   "anchorYOffset": "10",
                   "anchorUnits": "pixels"
               }
           ]}}
       
     ]
   }
```

4. Got recipients from envelope

GET {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "name": "Sender 1",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "email": "sender1email@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "ed850c16-be9b-45d1-b0a2-b06f9d043a33",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "66f3947d-eea4-450a-9f3a-6145607dba20",
            "clientUserId": "SenderOne",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "roleName": "SenderMember",
            "status": "created",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "recipientType": "signer"
        },
        {
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "requireUploadSignature": "false",
            "name": "Sender2",
            "firstName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "email": "sender2email@gmail.com",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "recipientIdGuid": "88f5e6e2-9e95-4d94-9501-0ebdfeece93b",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "4843e0fa-a69c-43ce-9638-e9d1c023ad27",
            "clientUserId": "Sender2C",
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "roleName": "SenderMember2",
            "status": "created",
            "completedCount": "0",
            "deliveryMethod": "email",
            "recipientType": "signer"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "seals": [],
    "witnesses": [],
    "notaries": [],
    "recipientCount": "2"
}
```

5 - Sent envelope

GET {{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}

```
{
     "status": "sent"
}
```

When I check the document, I do not see any sign tab:

[DocuSign Document with the tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXR5w.png)

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you follow our two how-to articles about this:

1. [How to create a template](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/create-template/)
2. [How to request a signature using a
   template](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote/)

Note that by putting the recipients as "placeholders" on the template, you can still define them differently for each envelope using the `templateRoles` object as long as you match the `roleName`. You will then get all the tabs that you defined to show on the envelope created from that templates.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-place works fine with sign tabs. So the issue is to figure out what's happening with your app.

First off, **most important** please do **not** create an envelope by using multiple API calls to build up the envelope unless there's a real good reason why your application requires that pattern.

In general, building up an envelope via multiple API calls is not an efficient use of the API and is not allowed per DocuSign's [API Usage Guidelines](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/api-guidelines/#:%7E:text=Your%20application%20should%20accomplish,faster%2C%20and%20takes%20longer.).

Instead, you can use one API call to create all aspects of the envelope and send it.

Easiest example to see how to use anchor tags with signHere tabs is the [API Request Builder live examples](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/). It enables you to try out the API and it then creates the SDK calls for you in various languages.

My guess from looking at your code is that the anchor strings are not matching with the document's text.